# gcc inline asm embedding pointer to .rodata in .text, x86

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to embed a pointer to a string in the code section using inline assembler.  But gcc is adding a $ to the start of the symbol name, causing a link error.
Here is a minimal example,

```
static const char str[] = "bar";
int main()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        "jmp    0f\n\t"
        ".long  %0\n\t"
        "0:"
        :
        : "i" ( str )
    );
    return 0;
}
```

building with

```
gcc -Wall -save-temps test.c -o test
```

gives the error

```
test.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `$str'
```

looking at the .s temp file, can see the additional $ prepended to str

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .section    .rodata
    .type   str, @object
    .size   str, 4
str:
    .string "bar"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
#APP
# 4 "test.c" 1
    jmp    0f
    .long  $str
    0:
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Think i am doing this the correct way, as the same approach works on ppc gcc,

```
<clip>
    b      0f
    .long  str
    0:
</clip>
```

Then again, maybe it is just "luck" it works for ppc.  Is the issue because $ is used as a prefix for immediates when using the AT&T synax ?

In this simple example, i can work around the issue by hardcoding the symbol name, "str", in the inline assembler, but really need it to be an input constraint to the inline assembler.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this working on x86 targets ?

Thanks,
- Luke

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens using clang, probably because the code generator doesn't know the operand is bing used in a .long rather than as an immediate instruction operand. You code try something like:

```
const char str[] = "bar";
#define string(str)    __asm__ __volatile__ \
( \ 
    "jmp    0f\n\t" \
    ".long  " #str "\n\t" \
    "0:" \                          
)
int main()
{       
string(str);
return 0;   
}
```

(I had to remove the "static" on str because the compiler optimized it out as not being referenced.)

Comment: That does fix the example i posted, but not the actual use case unfortunately.  Was actually using __FILE__, etc, so the gcc was generating temporary symbols like .LC0, then getting link errors looking for $.LC0.  Want to avoid generating symbol names in a macro, so as to avoid possible clashes (even with __LINE__ appeneded).  Think i have just found a solution though... the $ is being added because of the AT&T syntax, adding -masm=intel works correctly.  Thanks for having a look at this Richard, much appreciated.